# How to do a mysql equivalent of group_concat with multiple fields in jooq?

Tags: mysql, jooq

How can we achieve the equivalent of this statement in jooq?

```
select course.course_id, 
       group_concat(course_user.user_id, ":", course_user.current_state) 
from course 
left join course_user 
on course.course_id = course_user.course_id 
group by course.course_id;
```

The result of the above in mysql would be something like

```
1   58:COMPLETED,11908:ASSIGNED,11919:COMPLETED,11920:ASSIGNED
2   11913:PENDING_APPROVAL,11919:COMPLETED,11921:COMPLETED
```

How can we achieve this in jooq? The groupConcat in jooq takes only one Field parameter or takes one Field and one separator string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using groupConcat over concat in this way -

```
DSL.groupConcatDistinct(DSL.concat(COURSE_USER.USER_ID, DSL.val(":"), COURSE_USER.CURRENT_STATE))
```

For some reason if I do not use distinct, I get every entry as two values. Probably because it executes once for concat and again for group concat? If this is the case then it surely is less efficient. Until I figure out a better approach or if somebody here can give me a better approach, I will stick with this.